# Get all records from another table with pivot

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have three tables:

**comments**

```
id
```

**comment_links**

```
id | comment_id | link_id
```

**links**

```
id
```

I want to get all `Link`s associated with each `Comment`. As you can see, `CommentLink` should act as a pivot table, but I don't know how to set up the relationships to make this work. I think I need to use the [hasManyThrough relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through), but I'm not 100% sure.

Here are my current class relationships (they may be wrong):

**Comment.php:**

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function commentLinks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CommentLink', 'comment_id', 'id');
    }

    public function links()
    {
        // How do I fetch all links here using the pivot table?
    }
}
```

**CommentLink.php:**

```
class CommentLink extends Model
{
    public function comment()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Comment');
    }
    
    public function link()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Link', 'id', 'link_id');
    }
}
```

**Link.php:**

```
class Link extends Model
{
    public function commentLinks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\CommentLink', 'link_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

What do I need to do here to make this work?

Comment: Question - why not just place the `comment_id` directly on the link? Is it that links may be belong to multiple users?

Comment: It's because I also have another table called `post_links` where posts can also have links, so it's a shared table.

Comment: You must create a relationship between them. maybe a column that has the same values in both tables

Comment: create a column by the name of rel_col and the value of this column is 1 then create another column for another table again by the name of rel_col2 the value of this also must be 1 then use this in your model as one to many rel.

Comment: I've already set up relationships, I just don't know if they're correct. I also still need to set up the `hasManyThrough` relationship, but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I said you how you can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, just using the wrong class names.

```
class Link extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Comment');
    }
}

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function links()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Link');
    }
}
```

You don't actually need to have a class for your pivot table, but you can if you want.

This is quite a good guide on how to do this.
https://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/